# RxJava2, How to combine multi observable's result?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, retrofit, rx-java2

I am developing Android app.
I have a question about RxJava2.
Here is an example:

I have a list of user id. (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...)

```
val userIds = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I want to make a list of user data.
To get the user data, I should call "REST API". (Retrofit)
In this case, I should request multiple.

GET /users/1

GET /users/2

GET /users/3

GET /users/4

GET /users/5

...

```
fun getUsers(userIds: List<String>, callback: UsersLoadedCallback) {
    var userList = List<User>()

    val userObservables = mutableListOf<Observable<User>>()
    userIds.forEach {
        userObservables.add(UserService.getUser(it))
    }

    Observable.merge(userObservables)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe {
                userList.add(it)
            }
}
```

I knew this is wrong.
But I don't know how to fix this.
"join", "merge", "zip" ?
How should I do?

Comment: create a list of `getUser()` observables and use `Observable.fromIterable()` along with `.forEach()` construct to read out each subscription

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `fromIterable` and `concatMap`:

```java
Observable.fromIterable(userIds)
    .concatMap(userId -> 
        UserService.getUser(userId).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    )
    .toList()
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(users -> callback.onUsersLoaded(users), error -> { /* report */ });
```

Comment: this is the way to go

Comment: line 2: concatMap(userId  <--- userId is List

Comment: Check again: `userIds: List<String>` and is streamed via `fromIterable`. `userId` can't be `List`!